# Authorization Amplify API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm planning to build a React Application with AWS amplify (Graphql / Dynamodb database and Cognito authorization)  Therefore I would like to use the Amplify CLI.

The React Applications should have a login for users to create data and all others (no logged in users) can only read data like a blog or something.

After create and init amplify the "amplify add api" command in the CLI gives me the option to choose between API key and Cognito authorization. (I many followed this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7mwQaGo6P0))

At this point, I don't know what to choose because for the public part of the application I would like to take API Key and for the restricted (Login part) I would want to choose Cognito.

For me, it looks like a very basic question, but I could find a solution so far how to set up this.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: This has been widely discussed in amplify github issues and here is the final process to allow auth and unauth in an amplify based app : https://github.com/dabit3/appsync-auth-and-unauth